# como executar o SendKey do javascript apenas uma vez

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um página que ao abrir envia o comando F11 pela função javascript SendKey porém preciso que está função só execute uma vez alguém sabe como fazer isso, segue o código abaixo:

```
function requestFullScreen() {

var el = document.body;
//alert(el);
// Supports most browsers and their versions.
var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen  || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullScreen;
//alert(requestMethod);
if(requestMethod) {
alert("TESTE1");
// Native full screen.
requestMethod.call(el);

}else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject == "undefined"){
    //alert("TESTE2");
    // Older IE.
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

    if(wscript !== null) {
        $("#body").one('onload', function() {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        });


    }
  }
}
```

html

```
<body onload="getDados();enviarDados();requestFullScreen();" id="body">
```

A minha ideia é deixar a tela full porém a pagina precisa atualizar varias vezes com meu código toda vez que atualiza ele envia o F11 teria algum forma de enviar so da primeira vez

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque seu código na tag code. Para sua pergunta sugiro você usar local Storage e implementar sua lógica. Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Mais uma coisa para você ler a respeito do que queres fazer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282049/4312593

Comment: já conseguir fazer obrigado